# Sort with two criteria, string ascending, int ascending

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How can I perform a sort on two different criteria?

For example, I have person objects like:

`Person` with properties `FirstName` (string), `LastName`, and `Rank` (int).

Example data like so:

```
Xavier    Smith 1
Alexander Smith 2
Alexander Smith 1
Bob       Hawke 2
```

It should sort on FirstName alphabetically, then on rank, e.g. resulting:

```
Alexander Smith 1
Alexander Smith 2
Bob       Hawke 2
Xavier    Smith 1
```

So far, I have tried the following, but it isn't working properly:

`peopleList` is `List<Person>`

```
peopleList.Sort(new Comparison<Person>((x,y) => x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank)));
peopleList.Sort(new Comparison<Person>((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name)));
```

Thanks

**edit:** to avoid changing my code too much, I really want to keep list, if I change the above lines to:

```
peopleList.OrderBy(person => person.FirstName).ThenBy(person => person.Rank).ToList();
```

Would give the exact same list just sorted properly, correct?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**LINQ Approach**

With LINQ you can use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx):

```
var result = peopleList.OrderBy(p => p.FirstName).ThenBy(p => p.Rank);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you really need a `List<T>` add a `.ToList()` at the end.

If you want to use the `Sort` method then you'll need to write a custom comparer.

EDIT: using `ToList()` returns a new list. If you want to sort your existing list then you should use the `Sort` method which does not return a list but rather operates on the current list (it is a `void` method).

**Sort / Comparer Approach**

Use: `list.Sort(new PersonComparer());`

Here's the comparer code. It was adapted from the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) so I recommend reading the comments they used to understand why it is structured this way.

```
public class PersonComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (y == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int retval = x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);

                if (retval != 0)
                {
                    return retval;
                }
                else
                {
                    return x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really must read much more on LINQ, it seems to be making my life so much easier!

Comment: @baron see my edit, I commented on your question in your recent edit.

Comment: @baron I added a comparer that can be used with `Sort()`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer Ahmad

Comment: @baron you're welcome :) There are some other good answers here. The idea of CompareTo is to see whether the items are equal, greater or smaller then sort based on the integer return value. The comparer can certainly be reduced in size with some ternary operators used in return statements or lambdas as shown by others. If you intend to use this type of comparison in many places it helps to have a class, otherwise rare comparisons can be done in place without a new class.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers seem to be more elegant than this and they make me feel like more of a noob, however if you understand how to sort like this, you can sort any kind of list in any way without knowing much of anything. And there's no need to write a whole new class (though writing a comparer class can be useful if you sort other similar lists in other parts of your code).

```
peopleList.Sort((x, y) =>
    {
        int compare = x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
        if (compare != 0)
            return compare;

        compare = x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank);
        if (compare != 0)
            return compare;

        return x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You were actually really close with the in-place sorting lambda syntax.  You're just missing the fact that lambdas can be enclosed in their own scope:

```
peopleList.Sort(new Comparison<Person>((x,y) =>
{
    int result = x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
    return (result != 0) ? result : x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank);
}));
```

It's a little less effort than writing your own `IComparer<Person>`!

Comment: @Aaronaught very nice, but you need to flip the comparison. Compare FirstName first, then in the 2nd part of the ternary compare Rank.

Answer (score 4):

I like the LINQ answer. If that's not an option, you could always use

```
(x,y) => 2*string.Compare(x.Name,y.Name) + x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank)
```

so that the string compare always dominates unless it equals 0