# c# list comparer use two compare elements

Tags: c#

```
private class CompAdvertisements : IComparer<Advertisements>
{
private string OrderBy { get; set; }

public CompAdvertisements(string orderBy)
{
OrderBy = orderBy;
}

#region IComparer<Advertisements> Members

public int Compare(Advertisements x, Advertisements y)
{
return x.Country.Name.CompareTo(y.Country.Name);
```

Can i also user x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name); in comparer that i will compare with two elements lik order by something and order by something2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If the outer comparison indicates that your two elements (Country.Name) are the same, then you instead return the result of an inner comparison (somethingElse).  You can do that for an arbitrary depth of comparisons.

```
outerCompare = x.Country.Name.CompareTo(y.Country.Name);
if (outerCompare != 0)
{
    return outerCompare;
}
else
{
    return (x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
}
```

Comment: What if x is null, how to make that this element will be at the bottom ot at the top whern use sorting.

Comment: You should check for x and y being null if it's remotely possible in your code (including for people that reuse your code in the future).  However, since in your example you're just comparing two sets of attributes from the same two objects, if they are both null then they are equal (return 0) but if one is null and one is not null, they are not equal.  In that case return 1 if x is NOT null and -1 if y is not null.

Comment: I was under the impression that if you write x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name) and either x or y was null, then you'd get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: If you don't check x or y for being null that's what you get.  Depending on your application you may want to allow one or both to be null and check.

Answer (score 0):

Eric J. is right. You may also want to have a look at [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376628/sort-with-two-criteria-string-ascending-int-ascending) The answers there give several ways you can sort a List, and they also go into detail about using an IComparer object to perform a similar task to what you're doing.