# C# Sort items in a list, withing the list, that satisfy a condition

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

Essentially, I have a list in C# full of structs that look something like this (code may not be syntax appropriate)

```
public struct Numbers {
    public int DistanceFromArbitraryPoint;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

What I would like to do is sort a list such that:

1. Sort list by distance (already did this no problem).
2. For each Numbers that has a distance < SomeCriteria, sort those list items by the sum of X and Y, while not creating a new list. Simply rearrange the list.

The result would make this:

```
Distance 12, x 0, y 0;
Distance 4, x 20, y 20;
Distance 6, x 0, y 3;
```

After Step One:

```
Distance 4, x 20, y 20;
Distance 6, x 0, y 3;
Distance 12, x 0, y 0;
```

After step 2 (sort all by sum of X and Y if distance < 10)

```
Distance 6, x 0, y 3; // lower X and Y Sum, goes first
Distance 4, x 20, y 20;
Distance 12, x 0, y 0; // Distance higher than 10, remains unsorted
```

Comment: You don't filter those three items but this sounds as if you want that to do: _" For each Numbers that has a distance < SomeCriteria"_

Comment: Also, does _"while not creating a new list."_ mean that it's not allowed to use LINQ with a final `list = query.ToList()`?

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far? Let us not duplicate your efforts, besidesyou're expected to show some research and failed attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort with two criteria, string ascending, int ascending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376628/sort-with-two-criteria-string-ascending-int-ascending)

Comment: @SimonShine that will not work with orderby thenby. because there is a condition. and those items that does not satisfy condition should remain untouched.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I was ambiguous. It can certainly return a list, just not something like list.Where() that ends up cutting out anything it doesn't touch.

I tried using list.Where(), but it removes code. I tried orderBy ThenBy, but I can't specify a condition

Comment: @JapanRob, any chance that you give a feedback on my answer?

Comment: @ASh Apologies for wait, excellent answer, marked correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

more complex comparison method required here

```
var numbers = new List<Numbers>{ new Numbers(6,0,3),   new Numbers(12,0,0), 
                                 new Numbers(4,20,20), new Numbers(5,20,20)};       
int d = 10;

numbers.Sort((a,b)=>
             {
                 if (a.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint >= d && b.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint >= d)                         
                     return a.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint.CompareTo(b.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint);                        
                 if (a.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint >= d)
                     return 1;
                 if (b.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint >= d)
                     return -1;

                 int c = (a.X+a.Y).CompareTo(b.X+b.Y);                       
                 if (c == 0)
                     c = a.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint.CompareTo(b.DistanceFromArbitraryPoint);
                 return c;                       
             });
```

output:

```
6 (0,3); 4 (20,20); 5 (20,20); 12 (0,0)
```

`Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)` from `List<T>` is used, not Linq

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JhLYuP)

```
public struct Numbers
{
    public Numbers(int d, int x, int y)
    {
        DistanceFromArbitraryPoint  = d;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int DistanceFromArbitraryPoint;

    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} ({1},{2})", DistanceFromArbitraryPoint, X,Y);
    }
}
```